# CRM 2011 Custom ribbon button click running its functionality correctly but raises page error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a set of buttons on one of my custom entities ribbon and also one on account entity ribbon. When i click one of them, i'm seeing page error message on the status bar but all of them are running their functionalities correctly. When i debugged code with IE Developer Tools, i realized that it was releasing page error before my code's run. Does anyone have any idea about this situation?

Thanks in advance,

Ozer

Xml Code :

```
<RibbonDiffXml>
  <CustomActions>
    <CustomAction Id="NXM.account.Form.SearchMerchantInDB.CustomAction" Location="Mscrm.Form.account.MainTab.Workflow.Controls._children" Sequence="1">
      <CommandUIDefinition>
        <Button Id="NXM.account.Form.SearchMerchantInDB.Button" Command="NXM.account.Form.SearchMerchantInDB.Command" LabelText="Üye Firma / İş Yeri Sorgula" ToolTipTitle="Üye Firma / İş Yeri Sorgusu" ToolTipDescription="Firma / iş yerinin Üye Firma / İş Yeri olup olmadığı bilgisini sorgular" TemplateAlias="o1" Image16by16="$webresource:new_searchmagnifier16x16" Image32by32="$webresource:new_searchmagnifier32x32" />
      </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CustomAction>
  </CustomActions>
  <Templates>
    <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates"></RibbonTemplates>
  </Templates>
  <CommandDefinitions>
    <CommandDefinition Id="NXM.account.Form.SearchMerchantInDB.Command">
      <EnableRules></EnableRules>
      <DisplayRules></DisplayRules>
      <Actions>
        <JavaScriptFunction Library="$webresources:new_account" FunctionName="CheckIfMember" />
      </Actions>
    </CommandDefinition>
  </CommandDefinitions>
  <RuleDefinitions>
    <TabDisplayRules />
    <DisplayRules />
    <EnableRules />
  </RuleDefinitions>
  <LocLabels />
</RibbonDiffXml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a hard work I found the mistake. If you set your Library attribute as

> "$webresources:new_account"

when it should be

> "$webresource:new_account"

you will experience this error. I mean your code will run, when you put a "debugger" word to your function debug tools will catch but your page will give page error.

@Philip, @Grigory thank you guys for your efforts and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run debugger on the page then press "Ctrl + R" for refresh and then click your buttons.
Debugger should stop on the line where the error occurs.

Comment: I tried this several times. But there's another thing I think. Because debugger does not catch the error line. But giving Syntax Error on the right pane. It gives error on edit.aspx line 3 character 1

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the page may have raised an exception before your button click event (perhaps OnLoad) do you have any custom code which runs on this form onLoad? If so I would look at what that code is doing first to rule that out. Failing that if no other code is running (which can be confirmed by disabling all events on the form) does the page still error? If so then validate that the fields on the form have all attributes correctly defined, such as display name etc as sometimes this can cause a form to error.

Comment: Hi Philip, i get the page error on status bar after i click my button but before it runs its functionality. As you suggested, i tried to disabled all form events but it didn't work. My form also includes json2, jquery and rest operation javascript libraries which i copied from Crm Sdk. And a general functions library i coded and used before in my previous projects. Have you got an example for a display name which causes form error?

Comment: Does the page load correctly if all events are disabled and you don't click your ribbon bar button? e.g. Open the form, make a nomial field change and save the form? In terms of the fields are there are fields which have a blank display name as this can cause issues on the form. It does sound like the button is not finding the appropriate method to run. Perhaps you could post the xml behind the button and also the function you intend to be run onclick of the button.

Comment: Hi Philip, i added the script and xml codes to the question. The page loads correctly even if i don't disable form events. The button is finding its code to run. When i set a debugger to the start of its method and click the button, IE Developer Tools catches the breakpoint but before that time page gives error on the status bar. Then when I hit F5 (on IE developer tools) it runs the method(CheckIfMember) correctly and returns the result. Son I don't think that may method causes the error.

Comment: Hi @ÖzerKayhan thanks for posting the code. Having had a quick look through nothing immediately jumps out. When you see the error on the page if you try to close the window I assume you get the "Send Error to Microsoft" window. If so what do the details there reveal as "sometimes" this can give a clue to the underlying error. If that is no help it may be worth checking the versions of the other included libraries, particularly the json2.js library. I once had an issue with this libraery not loading correctly and getting cryptic errors. Sorry I can't be more help than that at the moment!

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort @Philip I will check the library version

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I had the same problem but my solution was slightly different. I referred to my custom Web Resource library as:

```
/WebResources/xxx_js_mylibary.js
```

when you can't have the .js part.

Instead,

```
/WebResources/xxx_js_mylibary
```

Hope that helps someone down the line. Thanks to the preceding participants in this conversation for steering me in the right direction.